# How to solve "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"

Tags: c

I'm solving C programming quiz.

The quiz problem was "what is the output of the following code snnipet?"

```
uint32_t v = 0xdeadbeef;
printf("%02x", (char *) v[0]);

or uint64_t?
```

Honestly I didn't understand the problem, so I tested on my local machine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t v = 0xdeadbeef;
    printf("%02x", (char *) v[0]);    /* (1) */

    int64_t w = 0xdeadbeef;
    printf("%02x", (char *) w[0]);    /* (2) */

}
```

I'm getting compile error on (1) and (2).

Here is the error message

> num1.c: In function ‘main’:
>   error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

So for the question on this post, **How can I test this code without compile error?**

Expected output : `de`, `ad`, `be`, `ef`, or `00`

Comment: The code's a little buggy -- you'll need to cast `v`, not `v[0]`. That is, `((char*)v)[0]`. That might also give you an idea as to the problem.

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste the quiz problem? Either the quiz is incorrect, or the quiz is correct and you copied it incorrectly.

Comment: I typed the all problem letter by letter

Comment: I just add expected output. with v, it's printing `deadbeefdeadbeef` which is not one of the answers.

Comment: Do you want me to share the quiz link?

Comment: one of the option is `efef`?

Comment: what will actually be output depends on if the underlying hardware is big or little Endian.   This format string: `"%02x"` will output only the contents of a single byte, as 2 hex digits.  So the 'expected output' is unrelated to the code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought I misunderstood your comment. I just tested with ((char *) v)[0] and it returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  Why am I getting segmentation fault???? this is horrible

Comment: ok. I'm trying to solve problem number 1 and 2 : (https://tc.gtisc.gatech.edu/cs3210/2017/spring/q/prep.txt)

Comment: @JohnBaek.: Yes that's the purpose of the whole thing...what do you understand from seg fault?

Comment: This should probably be `((char *) &v)[0]`. Then it would output either de or ef depending on endianness.

Comment: @coderredoc As far as I know, seg fault is that I'm accessing not allowed memory area. But I don't understand why I got this error. I'm thinking

Comment: @JohnBaek.: Yep..you went into right direction.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ((char *) &v)[0] seems right. It prints `fffffef` `ffffffef`. But it's 8 digits.

Comment: The compiler is correct. The code in the quiz problem is wrong. The only way it makes sense is to change `(char *)v[0]` to `((char *)&v)[0]` -- or, more likely, `((unsigned char *)&v)[0]`

Comment: @KeithThompson could you explain more about it?

Comment: The correct answer to the quiz is that the code fails to compile. You could either say there is no program output; or that the "output" of attempting to compile and run the program is a compiler error.

Comment: @M.M Yes but can you explain WHY the program is a compiler error? I can't just check the answer and go on. I have to fully understand why it's not working.

Comment: @JohnBaek yes, because you subscripted a value (`v`) which is neither array nor pointer nor vector. The subscript operator requires one of those things as operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem asks about the first byte of four bytes uint32_t arranged in memory layout. That depends on endianness. If you want to find out the output, you may check this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t v = 0xdeadbeef;
    char* pv = (char*)&v;
    printf("%02x\n", (uint8_t)pv[0]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's working. it's printing `ef`. It seems right answer.

Comment: And at the same time, I'm very confused.

Comment: What is the confusion?

Comment: `That depends on endianness`. I learned Endianness is the order of memory arrangement (I learned it about 3 years ago so I may misunderstand what it means). And how is it related to your answer?

Comment: If you machine is little endian, then it will show `ef`. And if it is big endian, it will show `de`. Please check [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Oh now I understand.

Comment: @abdullah better as `(uint8_t*)&v;` and include `inttypes.h` and `printf` with `PRIx8` (or at least use `hhx` as the format specifier)